# Mongodb schema advice for categories collection

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 2.6.7 where I have created Categories collection following the [MongoDB mode tree structure with array of ancestors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/) yet this model is really over complicating coding for me so I was wondering if someone can please advice me by the best model / schema design to follow in order to best achieve my Categories collection needs which are as follows:

```
A. Build a tree with unlimited levels of categories and sub-categories
B. For any node in the tree I can easily know the list of this node ancestors
C. For any node in the tree I can easily know if it has any child nodes or not
D. I can only create sub-nodes (sub-categories) to those categories not referenced by any item in the inventory
E. I can move any sub-node in the tree along with its child-nodes to a different node, sod for example if i have:
- 1
--11
---111
---112
---113
-----1131
-----1132
-----1133
--12
---121
---122
---123

so I can move node 113 with its sub-children 1131, 1132, 1133 and place 113 under 123 so that it will look like this:

- 1
--11
---111
---112
--12
---121
---122
---123
-----113
--------1131
--------1132
--------1133
```

My current categories collection design is as follows:

```
{ _id: "", 
  ancestors: [ ], 
  parent: "" 
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add in a field either for the immediate children or just to indicate that there are children:

```
{
    _id: "", 
    ancestors: [<_id's>], 
    "children" : [<_id's>]
}
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of `parent` was. This looks like a good schema design for A-C. D is something the application will need to enforce. E is not so bad to do with your design either, it just involves updating ancestors for all child nodes of the root node that is being relocated. B and E are in contention with each other - if you know the ancestors quickly by storing them on a node, you need to update all children when you relocate a subtree. B is most likely much more common than E, so the tradeoff of fast B for cumbersome E is reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since I might be updating a lot of documents to update ancestors, children arrays when re-allocating a specific node in the tree, is there a way to lock to the whole collection while doing so OR doing something like an atomic update to prevent possible problems if another app user tried to update the tree while the app is still updating the ancestors / children of the re-allocated node?
On a minor note, I understand that  db.collection.update() is atomic on a single document, so I am referring to being atomic on several documents update. Thanks